# How to hide an item from a list based on some attribute in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

in the admin view in the [rails_admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), I have the Cart model

```
Cart(id: integer, user_id: integer, status: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

and I don't want the admin to see it until it's status is confirmed. how do I hide it from the list view in rails_admin?

so I want something like this

```
if cart.status == 'new'
  hide
```

Answer (score 2):

the only way i saw possible is to stick with the cancan gem for this case the following code can do it

```
if user.admin?
  cannot :read, Cart, :status=> 'new'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the unconfirmed cart need to be in the list?

If not then it would be better to not put it in there.  As an example:

```
# carts_controller.rb
def index
  @carts = Cart.where( status: 'confirmed' )
end
```

You can also set up scopes, so your Cart has a method named 'confirmed':
[Scoping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)

Otherwise you can also call 'group'

```
@carts = Cart.group( :status )
```

Which will group your carts by status.

[Grouping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group)

Comment: I am talking about the [rails-admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) in the admin view of the cart model.